# How to enable encrypted DNS on Windows 11

Tags: dns, encryption, windows-11

I'm trying to enable encrypted DNS on Windows 11 (Pro), but I'm unable to do it using [instructions such as this on Bleeping Computer](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-11-includes-the-dns-over-https-privacy-feature-how-to-use/).

In that linked article, they have a screenshot that shows the option of "Preferred DNS encryption". However, when I go to that same screen, `Settings > Network & Internet > my connection > (my adapter) > DNS server assignment > Edit`, I do not get that option.

How do I get that to appear?

Note: I'm using Cloudflare DNS settings.

[image: screenshot of DNS settings]

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/765940/how-to-enable-dns-over-https-on-windows-11/

Comment: @Moab: Thanks! This worked. If you submit via an answer, happy to mark it as such so that you get the points.